# Проблема с методом contains()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Есть два квадрата, один из которых появляется в рандомном месте, а другой управляется мышкой, при соприкосновении они должны выводить "Ok" в окне, но когда квадраты соприкасаются ничего не происходит.

Код:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

color = (0, 0, 0)
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x, y = random.randrange(0, 500), random.randrange(0, 500)

fnt = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
text = fnt.render("Ok", 1, (color))

surf1 = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
surf1.fill((100, 100, 100))
rect1 = surf1.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

surf2 = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
surf2.fill((255, 255, 255))
rect2 = surf2.get_rect()

while True:
    sc.fill((0, 0, 0))
    sc.blit(surf1, rect1)
    sc.blit(surf2, rect2)
    sc.blit(text, (260, 20))

    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    if pygame.mouse.get_focused():
        rect2 = surf2.get_rect(center = (i.pos[0], i.pos[1]))

    if rect2.contains(rect1) == True:
        color = (200, 200, 200)

    if rect2.contains(rect1) == False:
        color = (0, 0, 0)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Вы меняете `color`, но оно нигде не применяется

Comment: text = fnt.render("Ok", 1, (color))  строка 9

Comment: color - это цвет текста. когда квадрат касается другого квадрата цвет меняется на тот который видно а когда не касается меняется на цвет фона и текста не видно

Comment: вы переписываете объект в `color` на другой, поэтому то, что было до цикла (строка 9) не имеет значения

Comment: я пробовал просто отображать текст без изменения цвета и результата не было значит не работает contains()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для пересечения прямоугольников используйте метод [Rect.colliderect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect), а `text = fnt.render("Ok", True, color)` нужно на каждой итерации заново задавать

Попробуйте:

```
import sys
import random

import pygame

pygame.init()

color = (0, 0, 0)
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x, y = random.randrange(0, 500), random.randrange(0, 500)

fnt = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)

surf1 = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
surf1.fill((100, 100, 100))
rect1 = surf1.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

surf2 = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
surf2.fill((255, 255, 255))
rect2 = surf2.get_rect()

while True:
    text = fnt.render("Ok", True, color)

    sc.fill((0, 0, 0))
    sc.blit(surf1, rect1)
    sc.blit(surf2, rect2)
    sc.blit(text, (260, 20))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            rect2 = surf2.get_rect(center=event.pos)
            break

    if rect2.colliderect(rect1):
        color = (200, 200, 200)
    else:
        color = (0, 0, 0)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: спасибо, код работает, но я хотел бы узнать почему не работает contains()?

Comment: Нашел ответ тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/41372223/5909792 @нехочувводитьимя, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: ещё раз спасибо я понял в чём проблема, теперь буду использовать colliderect

Comment: @нехочувводитьимя, пожалуйста :)